# Wrong request basePath when using Silex and HHVM

Tags: php, symfony, silex, hhvm

When I call `/api/v1/foo` Silex searches a route matching `/api/v1/foo` instead of `/foo`. How can I fix that?

My HHVM-Config:

```
VirtualHost {
    * {
        Pattern = .*
        RewriteRules {
            * {
                pattern = /api/v1/.?
                to = api/v1/index.php
                qsa = true
            }

            * {
                pattern = .?
                to = index.php
                qsa = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [fastcgi](https://github.com/facebook/hhvm/wiki/FastCGI) instead of the inbuilt webserver. You will find much more documentation about whatever webserver you choose (apache, nginx, etc) than ours and we are slowly getting out the webserver business entirely anyways.